# How to unfill Polygon in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

```
SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

g1.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent), t_rightarrow);

//this.Invalidate();

g1.DrawLines(pen_disable, t_rightarrow);
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you expect from your code and what do you observe instead?

Comment: I have filled the polygon with black color and now i want to remove color of that polygon.

Comment: Please [edit] your question for new information. What exactly does "remove color" mean? Draw in white? Make obscured other shapes behind it redraw themselves?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some confusion about how painting in windows works. In essence it follows the painters algorithms.

1. Write the background color to all pixels
2. Draw each shape in order, overwriting anything that was there before

So to 'unfill polygon' you just invalidate the control and call [DrawPolygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawpolygon?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instead of FillPolygon.

This is a bit of a simplification, there are also ways to redraw regions etc, but that is probably not needed.